# history.push() redirects the url but the component does not render (reactjs application)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my reactjs application, I've defined a this to happen after logging in successfully:

```
localStorage.setItem('token', token)
history.push('/home')
```

And, inside the routing component I've defined that if the token exists, user can enter the home:

```
{localStorage.getItem('token') &&
  <Route path = '/home' component = {Home} />
}
```

But the problem is that after getting the token and redirecting to the /home path, the Home component does not render even the condition of having the token is satisfied, and I need to refresh the page to render this component. Does anybody have any idea of what is happening? I really appreciate any help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) component code example. May we see all of *this* component, the `Home` component, and the component rendering the `Route` rendering `Home`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this`/`
so its going to be like this

```
{localStorage.getItem('token') &&
 <Route path = '/' component = {Home} />
}
```

Comment: Well, sorry, that's a mistake in writing the question; I've edited the post.

Comment: I have updated my answer so see if it works and let me know. Since you're navigating to the home page. there is no need to add the `/home` to the path. You should also bear in mind that how you arrange you routes is also going yo affect chances of the component showing or not